# button enable on grid checkbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, checkbox

I have one gridview which checkbox,

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GriduwgDocuments" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server"
            EnablePersistedSelection="true" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" GridLines="None"
            Width="960px"  PageSize="25">
                           <PagerSettings Position="Top"></PagerSettings>
            <RowStyle CssClass="result-grid-row" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="result-grid-row-alternate" />
            <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="result-grid-row-selected" />
            <HeaderStyle Height="20px" CssClass="result-grid-header" />
             <Columns>
             <asp:TemplateField >
     <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBxSelect" runat="server"  OnCheckedChanged="cbRowChanged_CheckedChanged" />  
     </ItemTemplate>

  </asp:TemplateField>
```

and button,

```
  <asp:Button ID="btnGetDocs" runat="server" Text="Download Selected Docs" 
                                                CssClass="Button" 
                                                Width="140px" Enabled="False" />
```

What I am trying to do is , when page load first time my button is `Enabled="False"` and as soon as client checked any checkbox of grid, my button should be `Enabled="true"` . I mean clickable.

on `OnCheckedChanged` of checkbox ,its goes to behind the code `cbRowChanged_CheckedChanged`.

please advice !!

Comment: What is inside `cbRowChanged_CheckedChanged` and what is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this via javascript. If you have jQuery available, it might look like this:

```js
$('#GriduwgDocuments input:checkbox').change(
    function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#btnGetDocs').attr("disabled", false);
        }
    });
```

Of course, you should also verify this server-side when the form is submitted., and depending on what client id mode you use on the page you may need to get the generated client id.

Comment: this is exactly I am trying to do in JavaScript.

Comment: i am getting "JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'prop'" error .

Comment: $('#btnGetDocs').attr("disabled", false);  just work as expected.

Comment: Fixed, thanks, though my understanding is jQuery 1.6 and later should use `.prop()`